# URL ReWritting rule for my url

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis-7

I need some clever regular expression writing in IIS7 to redirect traffic from one site to another, the pages are similar in structure but information needs re-writing.

Here's an example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/manufacturers/Name_of_Manufacturer_6828/Name_OF_Product_43146.htm
```

needs to be structured as the following

```
http://www.newsite.co.in/free-msds-download/name-of-manufacturer/name-of-product/
```

Here's what needs changing:

1. Only Alpha, Numeric and hyphen's allowed.
2. Change '_' to '-'.
3. Remove the '_NUMBER' directly after the manufacturer name and before the '/'.
4. Remove the '_NUMBER' directly after the product name and before the '.htm'.
5. Remove the '.htm' and replace with a '/'.

It needs writing into the code below please as a permanent 301 redirect:

Comment: It needs writing into what code?  What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/ there is some good information on how to do it here as well as examples.